# Generic method parameter with generic property throws T does not contain a definition error

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

I'm trying to abstract a method that currently takes in 2 parameters. Both parameters are of Class SecureEmail. Initially the types were specified, i want to make it generic now but i'm getting an error when assigning them, on the parameter that is also generic. I have added some code to explain below.

Initially AddInfo looked like this (Worked fine):

```
private void AddInfo(SecureEmail<emailforEmployees> email, SecureEmail<EmailtoAdmins>tempEmail)
{
  var emailtrail = new NotifyMe()
     {
        emailrequetid = email.Model.emailrequetid
     }   
}
```

I changed it to this:

```
private void AddInfo<T,U>(SecureEmail<T> email, SecureEmail<U>tempEmail)
{
  var emailtrail = new NotifyMe()
     {
        emailrequetid = email.Model.emailrequetid //error on emailrequetid 
            // T does not contain a definition for emailrequstid and no accessible extension method '' accepting a first arugment 'T' could be found.
     }   
}

public class Email
{
 public string from {get; set;}
}

public class SecureEmail<T> : Email
{
 public T Model {get; set;}
}

sendEmail(SecureEmail<TypeofEmail> email)
{
    var tempEmail = new SecureEmail<emailforEmployees>()
    {
        //populate
    }
     
  tempEmail.Model = new EmailtoAdmins()
  {
     /////Popuilate Model
  }
  
  AddInfo(email, tempEmail)
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to call AddInfo and specify any type i want for T.

Comment: If `Model` can be any type `T` how do you know it has a `emailrequetid` property? Perhaps you need a generic constraint? And why would `U` also have that, shouldn't there there just be one generic type `T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to use generics, its better to remove the dependency. I tested this and it cleaner:

```
private void AddInfo(NotifyMe emailtrail)
{
  Dosomething(emailtrail);
}

sendEmail(SecureEmail<TypeofEmail> email)
{
    var tempEmail = new SecureEmail<emailforEmployees>()
    {
        //populate
    }
     
  tempEmail.Model = new EmailtoAdmins()
  {
     /////Popuilate Model
  }
  
//move this here from Addinfo
var emailtrail = new NotifyMe()
         {
            emailrequetid = email.Model.emailrequetid //error on emailrequetid 
                // T does not contain a definition for emailrequstid and no accessible extension method '' accepting a first arugment 'T' could be found.
         }   

  AddInfo(emailtrail)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to make sure, the `emailrequetid` is defined. For example, you could define following interface:

```cs
public interface ISpecific
{
    public string EmailRequestId { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it to specify the `Model` has property `EmailRequestId`:

```cs
private void AddInfo<T,U>(SecureEmail<T> email, SecureEmail<U>tempEmail)
    where T : ISpecific
{
    var emailTrail = new NotifyMe()
    {
        EmailRequestId = email.Model.EmailRequestId
    };
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: This solution works but all the different types possible to be passed will have to be predefined negating the generics part of it. I think I'll just abstract it by taking it out of the method. I will make the emailtrail into a parameter of type INotifyMe and let the user of the method AddInfo define it.

Comment: Yes, @Aman, it's just one of ways. Also you could try to use [dynamic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/interop/using-type-dynamic) if you are sure only types with specific property is passed to the method.